# Parameter class of headers?

Tags: java, csv

I have a design question:
I want to write to a CSV file some data.

I have separate class to write data to CSV.

My problem is with the data and how to represent it:

- This data is composed of two lines of constant headers (main and secondary) and data lines that their values is changing.
- A line of headers is just a coma separated line of string values, my question is how to save these values?

For the parameter lines I created a parameters class that has a method: `getLine`.

For example:

```
Electrical params, , , Environment params
Voltage, Current, Resistance, Temperature, Humidity
2.3, 1.2, 0.5, 25c, 84%
```

The empty cells are for the CSV to look good.
My questions is about the first two lines:
What is the recommended way to treat the headers?

Should I create a headers class? Two classes (One for main and one for secondary)? Other?

Comment: I am confused. Can you please explain in more detail?

Comment: Sure. Updating the post.

Comment: I think that OP wants to store 3d array as csv.

Comment: Why do you even need "electrical params" ane environment params. All you need is your "secondary" header. its CSV, not table in Excel with joined cells

Comment: I know but this is the demand...

Comment: Why do you need so?

Comment: Because I need the secondary headers from the same kind under a main header that states their kind.

Comment: "their kind"? What kind?

Comment: Resistance, voltage and Current are electrical parameters for example...

Comment: I want some code.

Comment: As I mentioned this is a design question.

Comment: Since its a design question - stick to the secondary header that actually says what the values in the files are - like normal peaople do.

Comment: Questions like this may derive to questions like "is it possible to store hierarchical data or video right in CSV because of the demand?". Did you first read about the CSV format? RFC 4180 defines the header line as a **single** optional line, but tells nothing on a two-or-more lines for the header assuming that everything coming right after the very beginning or the first line is all data rows. You can of course emulate two-row headers like that, but how many tools (any Java CSV parsers, Excel, Google Spreadsheets) would support that as first-class headers? I'd assume zero.

Comment: The only major exclusion I can think of is MySQL that allows ignoring _n_ lines on `LOAD DATA INFILE` operation, but those _n_ lines are not headers for it, these lines are just ignored. Importing such "primary" and "secondary" headers in Excel (at least the 365 version) or Google Spreadsheets is not dictated, and they are always imported as data rows, so that the user chooses how many rows from the top as headers (and then made frozen to block column sorting). Simply speaking, these tools consider CSV files headerless, MySQL either, but the standard tells there can be one optional header only

Comment: If your toolchain needs the CSV to have two-rows dedicated for the header, then you may face issues in the future (not sure, how Java CSV libraries handle that). Did you probably consider encoding primary and secondary names into a single header? It will definitely make your code compatible with CSV, will work with Java libraries that can read named columns (i.e. `Map<String, String>` where the keyset is obtained from the header row). And finally, your CSV should contain data only, and not the way it _looks like_. Or consider data formats that can handle tree-structured data (XML, JSON).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how complex of a problem you are trying to solve. If you just need to keep track of a list of headers, then just keep it as a list of strings.

If you want a hierarchy of headers maybe a Header class and Subheader class?

```
public class Header {
  public String getName() {...}
  public ArrayList<Subheader> getSubheaders() {...}
  public int[] getColumnRange() {...}
}

public class Subheader {
  public String getName() {...}
  public int getColumn() {...}
}
```